# Determining if matrix is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's another one.

Say we have the matrix $
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -4 \\
1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$. I'm trying to determine whether it is diagonalizable or not. I found the eigenvalue 3, which is double solution for the polynomial. That should yield one subspace only right? Because when I check the solution online it says there are two eigenvectors, even though my subspace of eigenvalue 3 is 0-dimensional. What's up?

Comment: The eigenspace, even if there is only one, can have dimension $2$. Think about the identity matrix, it has only one eigenvalue and it certainly is diagonalizable.

Comment: 3 is not an eigenvalue of that matrix.

Comment: @GitGud: But the only diagonalizable $2\times 2$ matrix with repeated eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the diagonal matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \lambda&0\\0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}$!

Comment: @GitGud Thanks for the tip. But it didn't really address my question! If the eigenspace was 2-dimensional it would be fine. But it is 0-dimensional and the only eigenvector is 3. Unless I'm doing something wrong though!

Comment: Eigenspaces all have dimension 1 or greater. The matrix $A-\lambda I$ should not be invertible if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. That's a clue something went wrong.

Comment: @Alexandre As stated in the comment below mine, $3$ isn't an eigenvalue, that's why you get only the trivial solution. Eigenvalues are there exactly to get non-trivial solutions.

Comment: @user11977 I doublechecked my work and it seems to have a complex component. You were right! It's actually 3+2i and 3-2i. Sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Answer (score 2):

The matrix has characteristic polynomial $X^2-6X+13$ that has two complex (distinct) eigenvalues. So it's diagonalizable over the complex numbers, but not over the reals.

If the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -4 \\
1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then its characteristic polynomial is $X^2-6X+9$, which has $3$ as double root. It is not diagonalizable, though. Indeed, a $2\times 2$ matrix with a double eigenvalue is diagonalizable if and only if it *is* diagonal.

Comment: Exactly. I have a tendency to overlook complex numbers because I'm scared to death of them. It's childish and I should look into it sooner rather than later. Thanks!